# Android setContentView with animation not working properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-transitions

I'm trying to set an animation between two different layouts. Currently, I tried using this code to add an animation:

```
LayoutInflater inflator=getLayoutInflater();
View view=inflator.inflate(layoutsList.get(position), null, false);
view.setAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left));
setContentView(view);
```

This is the closest I've gotten, but this is what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0HJp.jpg

As you can see, it flashes white for some reason. The same thing happens when I use slide_out_right or fade_in.

How do I fix this or properly set an animation?

Comment: set a slide transition for your activity. [more info](https://developer.android.com/training/transitions/start-activity)

Comment: This does not help, as I am trying to add an animation for a change in the contentview layout, not the activity. The activity remains the same throughout the change in these 2 layouts

Comment: I would use fragments instead.